# Finding specific tree node in TreeView

Tags: c#, asp.net

I'm adding tree nodes to `TreeView` programmatically based on values from DB.

I need to add child nodes to those nodes before. The only way to locate them is by `myReportsNode.ChildNodes[int index]`, but this information is useless for me, as I need to find them by their value, or some unique id.

FindNode is not a good option, as I don't know exactly where they are, and looking for each node via itarating through the tree is a waste. I though of a dictionary for nodes.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to use a tree traversal. If there is some sort of ordering, you could make sure they are loaded into the tree reflecting that ordering, and you can use a depth-first search and have logarithmic complexity (every bit as efficient as a tree-based Dictionary). A dictionary of nodes would be a waste of memory, since you already have a tree structure you can use--that is, if there is some sort of ordering.

If you would give us some sort of idea of how the data is in the tree, I could help even more.

Comment: Thanks.You put me into the right direction for suitable solution. I simply ordered the data in my stored procedure and created the tree view based on that order.

Answer (score 1):

Use strategy of using three four columns in your database table.

```
1) nodeId
2) nodeText
3) nodeValue
4) parentId
```

When a node is clicked, send request via ajax to find if this id has child, if yes bring its childs and append below it. Else no child found, no need to append.